# Overcoming Downgrade Issue Detected While Moving from .NET 5 to 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-5, .net-6.0

I got hit with a weird issue when moving from Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022 and then from .NET 5 to .NET 6.  While all of the third-party apps updated, it turns out that any MS libraries referenced by those apps will not necessarily update.  While everything compiles and runs without issue, attempting to publish this solution constantly failed with a slew of "downgrade detected" errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is to capture the libraries causing the error and then going into the NuGet Manager, Browsing for each of those libraries and then installing the latest version.

Hope this helps anybody else that gets stuck!